# Angular 17 & NgxMarkdown: Error: renderer 'ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions' does not exist

Tags: angular, markdown, angular17, angular-ssr

**This angular app runs version 17 and has ssr included. Somehow when integrating ngx-markdown, this error message pops up:**

`Error: renderer 'ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions' does not exist`

**Here all relevant scripts that implemented NgxMarkdown, there are no other integrations or modules at all.**

article.component.ts

```js
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
    import { MarkdownModule, MarkdownComponent, provideMarkdown } from 'ngx-markdown';
    @Component({
        selector: 'article-component',
        templateUrl: './article.component.html',
        standalone: true,
        imports: [MarkdownModule, CommonModule,MarkdownComponent],
        providers: [provideMarkdown()],
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    })
    export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(
        ) { }
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
        }
    }
```

article.component.html

```html
<article>
<markdown>{{article.content}}</markdown>
</article>
```

app config

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(), provideClientHydration(), provideRouter(routes)]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

After going through you code, there was only a single problem i think, the versions needs to like so

```
"marked": "^9.1.6",
"ngx-markdown": "^17.1.1",
```

For both the packages to not error out, other than that your code works fine!

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/jorit-vasconezgerlach/angular-markdown-error-example)

---

I think you are missing the `importProvidersFrom(MarkdownModule.forRoot())` in the environment providers array!

app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { MarkdownModule } from 'ngx-markdown';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideRouter([]),
    importProvidersFrom(MarkdownModule.forRoot()), // <- changed here
  ],
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cybsyk?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.config.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Farticle%2Farticle.component.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Farticle%2Farticle.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: thank you for responding, unfortunately error still persists. i'm also still working on it

Comment: @jorit please share back with the issue replicated, will check it

Comment: here the extracted problem. https://github.com/jorit-vasconezgerlach/angular-markdown-error-example

npm install + ng serve resolves in this issue

Comment: thank you very much, those two things solved the error. the ngx markdown documentation uses `provideMarkdown()` instead of `importProvidersFrom(MarkdownModule.forRoot())` both seem to do the same thing. now uploading for ssr will be interesting 

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fork from the ngx-markdown repository and made modifications to the markdown.service.ts file, particularly in the extendsRendererForExtensions method. This method is responsible for setting up extensions, and it's designed to be idempotent, meaning you can call it multiple times without unintended side effects.

Here's the modified code:

```js
private extendsRendererForExtensions(renderer: Renderer): Renderer {
  let extendedRenderer = renderer as ExtendedRenderer;

  // Check if the renderer has already been extended
  if (extendedRenderer.ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions === true) {
    return renderer;
  }
  
  if (!(renderer instanceof ExtendedRenderer)) {
     extendedRenderer = new ExtendedRenderer(renderer.options);
  }

  // Apply additional extensions if they are provided
  if (this.extensions?.length > 0) {
    marked.use(...this.extensions);
  }

  // Mark the renderer as extended to avoid redundant extensions
  extendedRenderer.ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions = true;

  return extendedRenderer;
}
```

Now, it's important to note that the error you encountered, specifically renderer 'ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions' does not exist, is due to the fact that the original renderer was never initialized as an ExtendedRenderer. It was only cast to that type without being properly instantiated. By introducing the line extendedRenderer = new ExtendedRenderer(renderer.options);, we ensure that the renderer is initialized as an ExtendedRenderer before attempting to access or modify its properties. This correction should prevent the error from occurring.

This method now ensures that extendedRenderer.ɵNgxMarkdownRendererExtendedForExtensions is set to true without throwing an error.

I recommend generating an issue in the original ngx-markdown repository to bring it to the attention of the author. This way, the author can analyze and address the concern appropriately.